# Return a new string where everth xth character (starting at 0) is now followed by *?

Tags: python

I wanna write a function that takes a string, s, and an int, x. It should return a new string where every xth character (starting from zero) is now followed by an '*'.

So far I've tried this code:

```
def string_chunks(string, x):
    """
    >>> string_chunks("Once upon a time, in a land far, far away", 5)
    'O*nce u*pon a* time*, in *a lan*d far*, far* away*'
    """
    for ch in string:
        return ch + "*"
```

but I am very stuck and am unable to make it work.
I would appreciate any help. If you provide an answer, it would be nice if you could comment the code also.

Comment: I won't (and I don't think I should) give you the code, but what you need is to get the current index in your for-loop (you can do by keeping a separate variable, or by using enumerate etc).  Keep appending each character to a result string.  If the index mod x is zero (i.e. it is hitting the x-th char), append an extra asterisk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using a new string instead of a list

I thought it could be easier using a new string (ns) instead of a list to be joined, just adding each character of the original string (text = s) with a '*' after each multiple of the interval x (checked with the if multiple_of_x. To check if the n (index of the character of s) is a multiple I used n % x == 0 that is equal to zero only for multiple of x (ex.: 5 10 15, because 5 % 5 = 0, 15 % 5 = 0.... and so on). If the result of n % x in not 0, it will add only the character without the '*'.

```
def string_chunks(s,x=5):
    ns = ""
    for n,ch in enumerate(s):
        multiple_of_x = (n % x == 0)
        ns += ch + "*" if multiple_of_x else ch
    return ns

text = "Once upon a time, in a land far, far away"
print(string_chunks(text))
```

### Using a list

It can be done this way too.

```
def string_chunks(s,x=5):
    ns = []
    for n,ch in enumerate(s):
        multiple_of_interval = (n % x == 0)
        ns.append(ch + "*") if multiple_of_interval else ns.append(ch)
    ns = "".join(ns)
    return ns

text = "Once upon a time, in a land far, far away"
print(string_chunks(text))
```

Output

```
O*nce u*pon a* time*, in *a lan*d far*, far* away*
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn it into a list and every nth index append a `'*'`, then join it back to a string.

```
def string_chunks(string, x):
    string = list(string)
    for i in range(0, len(string)-1, 5):
        string[i] += '*'
    return ''.join(string)
```

Comment: Just noticed it was homework. Should slow down when I read... Please don’t be me OP. Take the extra time to actually learn the language and learn good coding habits as you’ll get nowhere if SO writes all your programs.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you do this:

```
for ch in string:
        return ch + "*"
```

This immediately exists the function. Instead, you want to create the whole string by doing something like this:

```
chunked_text = chunked_text + ch + "*"
```

and only after iterating over the whole string you want to return it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def string_chunks(string, x):
    """
    >>> 
    'O*nce u*pon a* time*, in *a lan*d far*, far* away*'
    """
    count = 0
    newstring = []
    for ch in string:
        count = count + 1
        if count == x:
            newstring.append("*")
            newstring.append(ch)
            count = 0
        else:
            newstring.append(ch)
    return("".join(str(x) for x in newstring))
output_s = string_chunks("Once upon a time, in a land far, far away", 5)
print output_s
```

Output:

```
Once* upon* a ti*me, i*n a l*and f*ar, f*ar aw*ay
```